# How to fix time selected bugs?

Tags: flutter, dart

I use customRadio to select the time. The problem is when I choose the time. The time I chose is not the same as the review details.

[image]

[image]

This picture is an example when I select the time 9.00 AM in the review details, the time indicated is 5.00 PM. Just like any other time when selected. Can anyone help me.

Code Time selected

```
Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
                    color: AppConst.bgLightBlue,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const SizedBox(height: 30),
                        const Text(
                          "Choose available time",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                              color: Color(0xFF172B37)),
                        ),
                        const SizedBox(height: 10),
                        customTabHeader(),
                        _tabIndex == 0
                            ? Column(
                                children: [
                                  customRadio("8:00 AM", "08:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("9:00 AM", "09:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("10:00 AM", "10:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("11:00 AM", "11:00:00.000Z"),
                                ],
                              )
                            : Column(
                                children: [
                                  customRadio("12:00 PM", "12:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("1:00 PM", "13:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("2:00 PM", "14:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("3:00 PM", "15:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("4:00 PM", "16:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("5:00 PM", "17:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("6:00 PM", "18:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("7:00 PM", "19:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("8:00 PM", "20:00:00.000Z"),
                                  customRadio("9:00 PM", "21:00:00.000Z"),
                                ],
                              ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
```

Code Detail Review

```
Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const Text("Date",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                              Text(timestampToDate(
                                  _appointment.appointmentUnixTime, 3)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              const Text("Time",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12)),
                              Text(timestampToDate(
                                  _appointment.appointmentUnixTime, 1)),
                            ],
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
```

Code TimeStampToDate

```
String timestampToDate(int timestamp, int type) {
  var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp);
  //var formatter = new DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
  var formattedDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(date).toString();
  if (type == 1) {
    formattedDate = DateFormat('hh:mm a').format(date).toString();
  } else if (type == 2) {
    formattedDate = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a').format(date).toString();
  } else if (type == 3) {
    formattedDate = DateFormat('EEE, d MMM, yyyy').format(date).toString();
  } else if (type == 4) {
    formattedDate =
        DateFormat('EEE, d MMM, yyyy hh:mm a').format(date).toString();
  } else if (type == 5) {
    formattedDate = DateFormat('d MMM').format(date).toString();
  }
  return formattedDate;
}
```

Code CustomRadio

```
Widget customRadio(String time, String time24) => Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(5.0),
            ),
            boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
              BoxShadow(
                  color: Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
                  blurRadius: 10.0,
                  offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0))
            ],
            color: Colors.white),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Text(
                time,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xFF2C3F4C)),
              ),
            ),
            Radio(
              value: time24,
              groupValue: _selectedTime,
              onChanged: (value) {
                setState(() {
                  _selectedTime = value.toString();
                  _nextMediumButtonAction = true;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code for timestampToDate function for better understanding.

Comment: Can you provide `customRadio` method body?

Comment: you're saving the selected time in _selectedTime but how this _selectedTime is reaching _appointment.appointmentUnixTime  ..? as your are using this to show the time. you need to store the _selectedTime in it...

Comment: @pixel Can you show an example in code sir?

Comment: where do you initialize `_appointment`?

Answer (score 0):

change the type of `_selectedTime` to `TimeOfDay`, then update `customRadio` mothod:

```
Widget customRadio(TimeOfDay time) {
    final localizations = MaterialLocalizations.of(context);
    final formattedTimeOfDay = localizations.formatTimeOfDay(time);
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
            Radius.circular(5.0),
          ),
          boxShadow: <BoxShadow>[
            BoxShadow(
                color: Color(0xFFE1EAF0),
                blurRadius: 10.0,
                offset: Offset(0.0, 1.0))
          ],
          color: Colors.white),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Text(
              formattedTimeOfDay,
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Color(0xFF2C3F4C)),
            ),
          ),
          Radio<TimeOfDay>(
            value: time,
            groupValue: _selectedTime,
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                _selectedTime = value;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

then use it like this:

```
Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 20, 20),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 30),
            const Text(
              "Choose available time",
              style: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                  color: Color(0xFF172B37)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            customTabHeader(),
            _tabIndex == 0
                ? Column(
                    children: [
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 8, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 9, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 11, minute: 0)),
                    ],
                  )
                : Column(
                    children: [
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 12, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 13, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 14, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 15, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 16, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 17, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 18, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 19, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 20, minute: 0)),
                      customRadio(const TimeOfDay(hour: 21, minute: 0)),
                    ],
                  ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

then pass the `_selectedTime` to the next page to show it in review details. and if you want to format the selected time using `DateTimeFormat`, do it like this:

```
String formatTimeOfDay(TimeOfDay tod) {
    final now = new DateTime.now();
    final dt = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, tod.hour, tod.minute);
    final format = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a');
    return format.format(dt);
}
```

Comment: Actually String timestampToDate(int timestamp, int type) {
  var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp, isUtc: true); . Me just add  isUtc: true to solve this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Use below function:

`Text(timestampToDate(appointmentUnixTime("2023-07-04", "09:00:00.000Z"), 1))`

Instead of :

`Text(timestampToDate(_appointment.appointmentUnixTime, 1))`

```
  int appointmentUnixTime(String yourDate, String selectedTime) {

    // Create a DateFormat object with the "yyyy-MM-dd" pattern.
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');

    // Format the DateTime object using the DateFormat object.
    String dateOnly = dateFormat.format(DateTime.parse(yourDate));

    // Create a DateFormat object with the desired format.
    DateFormat tempDate = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ');

    // Parse the Dart string into a DateTime object.
    DateTime dateTime = tempDate.parse("$dateOnly $selectedTime");

    return dateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch;
  }
```